# Simple text-right (Full Example)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I have a simple canvas and I want to put the button on bottom like it is but on the right of the canvas (aligned with the canvas on the right).

What am I missing? Why is the button all the way to the right of the screen?

```css
#signature {
  background: #000;
  width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <canvas class="signatureCanvas" id="signature"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-right">
      <button uib-tooltip="Upload Signature" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is going to the right of the full div. Your canvas is set to 400px. You could set to 400px and make sure to center the div like the canvas. Here is how you could do it:

```
.text-right {
    text-align: right;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: the width was just an example. I don't have any width set to the canvas in my code. I want this to be responsive

Comment: You need to post more code then. How are you setting the canvas width? It would be the same way you set this div.

Comment: .signatureCanvas {
    border:1px solid grey;
    width: 450px;
    height: 130px;
}

Comment: Then your width in text-right would be 450px or better yet, create a class used by both that you can specify and then change to make responsive.